# Dataframe tranposition and mapping

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, python-3.6

I need to perform two sample t-test, for which I have to transpose my sample file and map values from another csv file to the sample file. I am new to python, so far I have tried this:

```
with open('project.csv') as f_project:
    df = pd.read_csv('project.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype= 'unicode', 
    error_bad_lines=False)
    df.set_index('TaxID', inplace=True)
    df_kraken = df.T
    df_meta = pd.read_csv('Meta3251.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype= 'unicode', 
    error_bad_lines=False, usecols = ['SRA ID', '(0/1)'])
    df_kraken['Meta'] = df_kraken['TaxID'].map(df_meta.set_index('SRA ID')
    ['(0/1)'])
```

My sample file dataframe after transposition looks like this:

```
                    333046  1049    337090
PRJEB3251_ERR169499 0.05    0.03    0.01
PRJEB3251_ERR169500 0       0       0
PRJEB3251_ERR169501 0       0       0
PRJEB3251_ERR169502 0.05    0       0
PRJEB3251_ERR169503 0.03    1.9     0
PRJEB3251_ERR169507 0.01    0       0
PRJEB3251_ERR169508 0       0.1     0
PRJEB3251_ERR169509 0       0.05    0
```

The index is not been set as TaxID.

I have another csv file which T have taken as another dataframe so that I can map the values. It looks like

```
SRA ID     (0/1)
ERR169611   1
ERR169610   1
ERR169609   1
ERR169608   1
ERR169607   0
ERR169606   0
ERR169605   1
ERR169604   1
ERR169484   0
```

I need to map the zero one values to the first column of 1st dataframe. Im stuck with the error : KeyError: 'TaxID'
Any hepl regarding this will be highly appreciated.

After you suggestion I have this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('project.csv').set_index('ID').T
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Project ID'})
df_meta = pd.read_csv('Meta3251.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype= 'unicode', 
error_bad_lines=False, usecols = ['SRA ID', '(0/1)'])
df['KEY'] = df['Project ID'].str.split('_').str[1]
df['Meta ID'] = df['KEY'].replace(dict(zip(df_meta['SRA ID'], df['(Project 
ID)'])))
df.to_csv('R.csv')
```

After this I have the following result:

```
        Project ID              333046 1049     KEY     Meta ID
        0   PRJEB3251_ERR169499 0.05  0.03    ERR169499 PRJEB3251_ERR169636                                
        1   PRJEB3251_ERR169500 0       0    ERR169500  PRJEB3251_ERR169635                           
        2   PRJEB3251_ERR169501 0       0    ERR169501  PRJEB3251_ERR169626                           
        3   PRJEB3251_ERR169502 0.05    0    ERR169502  PRJEB3251_ERR169625
```

I have the index but the good part is now im able to rename my column, the mapping is not working though.

Comment: You set `TaxID` as the index so it is no longer a column. You can access it with df_kraken.index. Do you need to have `TaxID` as the index?

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that could work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('project.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype= 'unicode',     error_bad_lines=False)
df.set_index('TaxID', inplace=True)
df_kraken = df.T.reset_index() # Make sure 'TaxID' is a column
df_meta = pd.read_csv('Meta3251.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype= 'unicode', error_bad_lines=False, usecols = ['SRA ID', '(0/1)'])
# In your example the second dataframe only matches what's after the '_'
# so you can isolate that part
df_kraken['KEY'] = df_kraken['TaxID'].str.split('_').str[1]
df_kraken['Meta'] = df_kraken['KEY'].replace(dict(zip(meta['SRA'], meta['ID'])))
```

### EDIT

The question has been edited.
After read_csv() (first line):

```
  TaxID   PRJEB3251_ERR169499 PRJEB3251_ERR169500 PRJEB3251_ERR169501
0 333046  0.05                      0                     0
1 1049    0.03                      0                     0
2 337090  0.01                      0                     0
3 288681  3.6                       0                     0
4 267889  0.02                      0                     0
...
```

Then

```
df = df.set_index('TaxID').T
print(df)
TaxID                 333046  1049    337090    
PRJEB3251_ERR169499    0.05    0.03    0.01    
PRJEB3251_ERR169500    0.00    0.00    0.00   
PRJEB3251_ERR169501    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Note that at this point `TaxID` is the name of the *columns* index, not of the row index. If you want to have `TaxID` as a column:

```
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'TaxID'})
```

To avoid confusion you can remove `TaxID` from the column name:

```
df.columns.name = None
```

Comment: Did you run the line with `.reset_index()`?

Comment: So how does your dataframe look like after this line? can you show the result of `df.columns`?

Comment: index                                333046 1049  
    0    PRJEB3251_ERR169499 0.05          0.03
    1 PRJEB3251_ERR169500 0          0
    2 PRJEB3251_ERR169501 0          0
    3 PRJEB3251_ERR169502 0.05          0
    4 PRJEB3251_ERR169503 0.03          1.9

Comment: So you do not have a TaxID column? Can you edit your question and show how the dataframe looks like right after the first `read_csv()`?

Comment: edited the answer: set_index() takes an existing column to use it as an index. To rename the index use rename_axis()

Comment: after this Im getting (0, '333046')
as my column header and the error still persists

Comment: Can you describe step by step what you did? I am not getting any error with the steps described above. Maybe start an answer so that it is easier to read? At each step can you show what your dataframe looks like?